# sed select range and change one whole line

Tags: sed

```
#!/bin/bash
run_middle.sh
if [ "$value" = "Analyzer" ]; then
  strname="$java_class_name.$value"
  minmem="-Xms1028m"
  maxmem="-Xmx1028m"
elif [ "$value" = "DE2Wizard" ]; then
  strname="$java_class_name.$java_m_de2_wizard.$value $java_m_root_path"
  minmem="-Xms128m"
  maxmem="-Xmx128m"
elif [ "$value" = "ReportGenerator" ]; then
  strname="$java_class_name.$java_m_simple_process.report.$value"
  minmem="-Xms128m"
  maxmem="-Xmx128m"
fi
```

this is my code and i want to change minmem and maxmem
so i tried this code but it doesn't work... what's wrong??

```
sed -n '/if \[ "$value" = "Analyzer" \];/,/maxmem/ {/minmem/ c\minmem=-Xms128m };' run_middle.sh
sed -n '/if \[ "$value" = "DE2Wizard" \];/,/maxmem/ {/minmem/ c\minmem=-Xms128m };' run_middle.sh
```

Comment: Welcome Oaias, your question is unclear. What is the expected change? Please provide expected result.

Comment: Attempting to modify shell scripts with `sed` is a horribly brittle idea anyway. Change the shell script so you can override the default values from the command line with an option or something.

Comment: Is 1028m a typo for 1024m or 128m?

Comment: The actual problem with your attempt seems to be that you _only_ print out the modified text, to standard output instead of back to the file which presumably you are trying to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Reading a bit between the lines, here is a refactoring which allows you to override the minimum memory setting for the two first cases with a command-line argument without modifying your script after refactoring it.

I also replaced the `if` clauses with a `case` clause for improved legibility and reduced code repetitivity.

```
#!/bin/bash
# run_middle.sh <- I'm guessing this was a comment, not the script calling itself?
case $value in
  "Analyzer")
   strname="$java_class_name.$value"
    minmem="${1--Xms1028m}"
    maxmem="-Xmx1028m";;
  "DE2Wizard")
    strname="$java_class_name.$java_m_de2_wizard.$value $java_m_root_path"
    minmem="${1--Xms128m}"
    maxmem="-Xmx128m";;
  "ReportGenerator")
    strname="$java_class_name.$java_m_simple_process.report.$value"
    minmem="-Xms128m"
    maxmem="-Xmx128m";;
esac
```

Just to spell this out, `./run_middle.sh` will run with `minmem="-XMs1028m` for `"Analyzer"` and `minmem="-Xms128m"` for `"DE2Wizard"`, and if you call it with an argument, it will use that argument for `minmem` in these two cases instead. So, instead of your `sed` script, just run it with

```
./run_middle.sh -Xms128m
```

I obviously had to guess what you are actually hoping to accomplish here; if this is completely a wrong guess, perhaps elaborate on what you actually want to accomplish.

Self-modifying code is problematic for many reasons, not least of which is that you want to have your scripts in version control. (Learn it now. You are wasting your time and that of your colleagues if you are not using version control.)

Tangentially, calling `sed` twice on the same file is something you usually want to avoid. `sed` is a scripting language; it is often not hard to combine multiple commands into a single invocation.